# I'm trying to add an arbitrary value to Magento checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I am trying to add an arbitrary amount to the order amount

in this file \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Payment.php

IN this function

```
public function setOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
```

I tried adding these 2 lines

```
$this->_order->setBaseGrandTotal(29);

$this->_order->setGrandTotal(29);
```

Why is the order amount not changing to $29 ?

Is this the correct way to add an arbitrary amount to an order value ?

Thanks

Comment: $this->_order->setGrandTotal() + 29

Comment: Yes $this->_order->setGrandTotal(29) should atleast set it to 29 isn't it ?

Comment: I dont know,how is that method defined?

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever change core files like this, because of upgrading issues.

I would advice to use an observer.
You can listen for the event sales_quote_add_item and change grand total programmatically with:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->setOriginalCustomPrice([your price]);
```